# How to add dashed line and don't show a line between marks in syncfusion_flutter_charts in certain conditions

Tags: flutter, charts, flutter-animation, linechart, syncfusion

[image]

As shown in the diagram based on the date if the user didn't perform any action in 3 days there must be no line between 2 points and if the action is after 2 days show a dashed line between points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requirement "how to add dashed and don’t show a line between marks" can be achieved by using the [onCreateRenderer](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/CartesianSeries/onCreateRenderer.html) callback that is available in chart series. To render a dashed line for the specific segment using the current segment index value, the existing line series renderer class can be overridden with a custom line series renderer class to get all series segment index value. You can also achieve the space between the points by using empty points.

Screenshot:

[image]

Sample: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hObaBHZi1Gvk2yeRg0XGHjmbJUWWKh3Y/view?usp=share_link